# Image input missing from POST request

Tags: html, django, post, django-templates

I have an `input` field corresponding to a Django `ImageField` in a Django template. Rendered, the HTML looks like:

```
<form action="/accounts/username/" 
      method="post" 
      id="profile_form"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
... (other input fields and elements)
<input form="profile_form" id="id_profile_pic" name="profile_pic" type="file" />
```

The corresponding `View` is an `UpdateView`. I found `request.FILES` to be empty and `request.cleaned_data` to contain `'profile_pic': None`.

I used firebug to track the POST data. It contained other fields but not `profile_pic`.

What are my sins? Why is the file not uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I somehow I copied the rendered HTML wrong! The real problem was that the form id used in input was incorrect and this was the reason for the file not getting uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Is this because of the code `form="profile_form"`? I would try putting the `<input>` inside the `<form>` as in the traditional model, because my first suspicion would be that the unusual form structure is to blame.

Let me know if I am wrong though.

Comment: Sadly, you're wrong. All the other input fields are similarly structured outside the form tag and still get POSTed to the server. I should also mention that out of superstition I did try putting the file input tag within the form, but that didn't help either.

For your reference, see the `form` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Attributes

Comment: My second guess would be to change _just_ the input type, eg. to a text input, and verify it gets transmitted. Then you confirm the problem is purely about file inputs, which is most likely anyway because they require lots of unusual handling.

Comment: Yes, all the other fields get submitted successfully. Hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: Incidentally I solved this problem in a recent app by using [asynchronous uploads to S3](http://fineuploader.com), effectively cutting them out of the POST request entirely; the server just receives the S3 URL as a hidden input. It's a fair amount of JS to get the workflow tidy, but it leads to a very pleasant user experience and it reduces load on your server.

Comment: Looks neat. Thanks, I'll give it a try, though I'd definitely like to understand the problem with my code if someone can figure it out.